# How do I turn a document.getElementById(id) element into a jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm actually surprised this question is not asked before:

I generate elements with:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = (some string with id's in it);
```

for example.

And I want to use jQuery (to update the CSS of the children of elements).

As those elements are created dynamically a simple:

```
$("#id")
```

doesn't work.

(It returns `n.fn.init[0]` objects).

How do I get a jQuery object from a HTML DOM object?

Comment: It's probably just a timing issue.

Comment: If `document.getElementById(id)` works then `$('#id')` will work just the same - _if_ you execute both commands at the same time!

Comment: No, somehow it didn't, I literally used the $("#id") at the same time (in the same script, on the same line) as the $(document.getElementById(id)) and the latter worked where the former didn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply do this:

```
$(document.getElementById(id))
```

you can use it as a jquery object:

```
$(document.getElementById(id)).children().css("opacity", "" + opacityTotal);
```

Comment: This doesn't make any difference with the simple `$('#id')`, jQuery uses `document.getElementById` under the hood with id selectors. If you've problems with getting a jQuery object using an id selector with dynamic elements, it's probably a timing issue.

Comment: I think the OP just wanted fns like `children` to be available on his elements, so he selected the element again in a jQuery call. Not sure what you mean by timing issue?

Comment: @weltschmerz Timing = they're attempting to retrieve an element which is not created yet.

Comment: @Teemu I understand, I just don't think that was the OP's issue.

Comment: No it wasn't, when I tried to access the element after a 5 second timer it still didn't find the element (i.e. the $("#id") selector still returned n.fn.init[0]) with the $(document.getElementById(id)) I could access the elements right after they were created...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using innerHTML to generate DOM elements you might need to access the from parent [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) and then initialize the jQuery array on it (with $)

```js
const container=document.getElementById(id);

container.innerHTML = '<div>...</div>'
$(container.children)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update the css of the dynamically added children in the document simply as:

```
$(document).find(".classOfYourDynamicallyAddedChildrens").css({"color":"red"});
```

Comment: Probably, but I want to add different css for different ids, using a class is not going to work here...